# how part queryset in Temokate

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Got code on Python 2.7 user Django how i can parse dishs_list in template?

```
userorder = UserOrder.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id,
                                             is_closed=0)
dishs = UserOrderItem.objects.filter(order_id=userorder[0].id).values('dish_id') \
            .annotate(count=Count('dish_id'))

dishs_list = list()
for d in dishs:
    dish = Dish.objects.filter(id=d['dish_id'])
    shop = Shop.objects.filter(id=dish[0].shop_id)
    dishs_list.append([d, dish, shop])
```

Have print(dishs_list)

```
[[{'count': 8, 'dish_id': 1}, <QuerySet [<Dish: Суши>]>, <QuerySet [<Shop: Суши Ями>]>], [{'count': 5, 'dish_id': 2}, <QuerySet [<Dish: Муши>]>, <QuerySet [<Shop: Суши Ями>]>]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{% for dash_item in dash_list %}{{dash_item.0.count}}{{dash_item.0.dash_id}}{{dash_item.1}}{{dash_item.2}}{% endfor %}`

Here `{{dash_item}}` is again a list so used `{{dash_item.0}}` to get the first element and similarly `{{dash_item.1}}` and `{{dash_item.2}}` to get the 2nd and 3rd items respectively.